# how to use html select value in the same page for getting records from database

Tags: html, jsp

I want to use the value from the select in the same page for jsp code to get the records according to city name.

```html
<select name="city" required="" style="width:120px;height: 35px;">
    <option>Select City</option>
    <option>Lucknow</option>
    <option>Agra</option>
    <option>Sitapur</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you using  `java script` or `jQuery ` ?

Comment: I am using javascript